# Json to string in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I have an ajax request with POST method. The request posts a Json data to server. I want to parse this json to a String like this:

```
 @POST
 @Path("file/save")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public void save(String content) {
 }
```

I got this error everytime I try to make a request to server:

"Error 400 Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token"

Here's the Post request in details:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8181/file/save
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:379
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:JSESSIONID=0AFC5FF7F201391DD67CCB0DA1BCD25C
Host:localhost:8181
Origin:http://localhost:8181
Referer:http://localhost:8181
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Query String Parameters

Request Payload
<my json data>

Response Headers
Cache-Control:must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length:1369
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Wed, 11 Sep 2013 03:11:03 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

How could I fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What, **exactly,** is the HTTP POST request which produces the 400? Please include all headers and the body.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your JAX-RS implementation (Jersey in this case) doesn't know how to map `application/json` content into a `String`. You'll need to register a `MessageBodyReader<String>` implementation that is annotated with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

**Addendum**

Implementing a `MessageBodyReader` that converts to `String` is straightforward.

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JsonStringReader implements MessageBodyReader<String>
{
   @Override
   public boolean isReadable(
         Class<?> type, 
         Type genericType, 
         Annotation[] annotations, 
         MediaType mediaType
      )
   {return type == String.class;}

   @Override
   public String readFrom(
         Class<String> type, 
         Type genericType,
         Annotation[] annotations, 
         MediaType mediaType,
         MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, 
         InputStream entityStream
      ) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
   {
      final String charsetName = mediaType.getParameters().get(MediaType.CHARSET_PARAMETER);
      final Charset charset = charsetName == null ? Charset.forName("UTF-8") : Charset.forName(charsetName);
      final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entityStream, charset);
      final CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.allocate(1024);
      while (reader.read(buffer) != -1)
      {
         buffer.flip();
         builder.append(buffer);
         buffer.clear();
      }
      return builder.toString();
   }
}
```

There are several ways to register a entity provider with a JAX-RS implementation. The way that's probably easier with Jersey is to add the following to your `web.xml`:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>pkg.that.contains.the.messagereader</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Further information on creating entity providers for Jersey can be found here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html

More information on configuring Jersey can be found here: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.html

Comment: On a stylistic note, having a resource called "file/save" that you only POST to is not truly RESTful. In true RESTful style, you might have a resource named "files" from which GET returns a list of existing content URI's, and from which POST adds a new resource and returns its URI via an HTTP 201 Created response.